# Increment position if string data array is different C# (Unity)

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I need help about a scoreboard I am making. Here's the scoreboard I want to achieve:

[image]

I actually have four tables and each table has its own scoreboard, but for this question only for table 1 is I need so here's how I am creating this kind of scoreboard.

Now, so far I have done this:

```
if (gametable_no == 1)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < tzPlayInfo.Instance.bc_gametable_history_list.Count; i++)
    {
        newString[0] += tzPlayInfo.Instance.bc_gametable_history_list[i].r;
        newString[0] += ",";
    }
    string[] groupedString = newString[0].Split(',');

    foreach (string allchars in groupedString)
    {
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;

        GameObject o = Instantiate(prefab_big_road[0]) as GameObject;
        o.transform.SetParent(pos_big_road[0]);
        o.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;
        o.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(2.0f, -5.0f, 0f);
        o.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(o.transform.localPosition.x + x,
            o.transform.localPosition.y + y, o.transform.localPosition.z);

        if (allchars.Contains(playerwinnopairboth))
        {
            o.GetComponent<UISprite>().spriteName = "layout_player_bigline-01";
            NGUITools.SetActive(o, true);
        }

        if (allchars.Contains(bankerwinnopairboth))
        {
            o.GetComponent<UISprite>().spriteName = "layout_banker_bigline-01";
            NGUITools.SetActive(o, true);
        }

        if (allchars.Contains(tienopairboth))
        {
            o.GetComponent<UISprite>().spriteName = "layout_tie_bigline-01";
            NGUITools.SetActive(o, true);
        }
    }
}
```

This code will achieve only like this:

[image]

The output is generated randomly so for example I have this output data:

```
Gametable 1 history : P  ,P  ,P  ,B   ,B P,P P,TBP
```

I need to know if the character is **changing** in the `gametable 1 history data`.

For example: *The output must be like this*

[image]

If the value is not changing like `P  ,P  ,P` then the position will only increment on the y axis, and then if the next value is different like `B   ,` then it will move to the x axis.

Is there a way of detecting if the character on your array of string is different from the other value?

**EDITED**

```
string[] newString = new string[4];

string[,] table = new string[70, 70];

string previousValue = "placeholder";
int xIndex = -1;
int yIndex = 0;

// First table
if (gametable_no == 1)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < tzPlayInfo.Instance.bc_gametable_history_list.Count; i++)
    {
        newString[0] += tzPlayInfo.Instance.bc_gametable_history_list[i].r;
        newString[0] += ",";
    }

    //string[] groupedString = GroupString(newString[0]);
    string[] groupedString = newString[0].Split(',');
    foreach (var allchars in groupedString)
    {
        GameObject o = Instantiate(prefab_big_road[0]) as GameObject;
        o.transform.SetParent(pos_big_road[0]);
        o.transform.localScale = Vector3.one;

        if (table.GetLength(0) < xIndex)
        {
            break;
        }

        if (allchars.Equals(previousValue) && table.GetLength(1) < yIndex)
        {
            yIndex += 15;
            table[xIndex, yIndex] = allchars;
        }
        else
        {
            xIndex += 15;
            yIndex = 0;
            table[xIndex, yIndex] = allchars;
        }
        previousValue = allchars;

        o.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(xIndex, yIndex, 0f);

        // Match the sprites
        if (previousValue.Contains(playerwinnopairboth))
        {
            o.GetComponent<UISprite>().spriteName = "layout_player_bigline-01";
            NGUITools.SetActive(o, true);
        }

        if (previousValue.Contains(bankerwinnopairboth))
        {
            o.GetComponent<UISprite>().spriteName = "layout_banker_bigline-01";
            NGUITools.SetActive(o, true);
        }

        if (previousValue.Contains(tienopairboth))
        {
            o.GetComponent<UISprite>().spriteName = "layout_tie_bigline-01";
            NGUITools.SetActive(o, true);
        }
    }
```

It only generates few prefabs:

[image]

Although I have already generated this data:

[image]

In my UI it only shows two:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a multi-dimensional array as a table.
Maybe something like this?

```
string[,] table = new string[30, 6];

string previousValue = "placeholder";
int xIndex = -1;
int yIndex = 0;

foreach (var value in groupedString)
{
    if (table.GetLength(0) < xIndex)
    {
         break;
    }

    if (value.Equals(previousValue) && yIndex < table.GetLength(1))
    {
        yIndex += 1;
        table[xIndex, yIndex] = value;
    }
    else
    {
        xIndex += 1;
        yIndex = 0;
        table[xIndex, yIndex] = value;
    }
    previousValue = value;
}
```

Now you should have a table containing all the values, which you can then display on your UI and match the correct sprite accordingly.

Comment: Can i ask first what is this sir I'm sorry `string[,] table = new string[6, 30]`

Comment: and the `string previousValue = "placeholder"` ?

Comment: The string[,] is a multidimensional array. If you visualize it, it would be like your image you uploaded. 
If you type table[0,0], you would access the top left cell. table[1,0] the one below. table[0,1] the 2nd row, first cell and so on.

The numbers in the initialization of the array (first line) should be the dimensions of your table. 
In my example, it is 6 Deep and 30 Long.

Comment: "placeholder" is a placeholder which gets overwritten by the previousvalue on the first foreach iteration. It's first value should be anything as long as it isnt a value contained in your groupedString.

Comment: I edited my question so my code should be like that.

Comment: I edited my  code to add checks for array lengths which prevent index out of range errors. 

Let me know if the code works for you!

Comment: `table.GetLength(2)` this cannot be converted from int to bool

Comment: Whoops. my bad. Should be fixed now

Comment: Why it doesn't show up sir? Here is the output of your code https://imgur.com/a/26tm8lo . The 01.big_road is the `gametable 1 history`

Comment: I would recommend to Instantiate the objects in a seperate method, based on their position in the array. It looks to me that you are now instantiating them on top of eachother.

I am now at work and cannot write your code for you. I've merely given you a push in the right direction.

Comment: alright sir . Thanks I'll push your code more. Thank you. Hope i can do it

Comment: Hi sir . The code you given has this value only . And it has an error `array is out of range`. Please see my edit

Comment: You should only increase the X and Y index by 1, at the positions i set in my code. Do not change this.

In you want to generate a new vector using the X and Y coördinates, mutiply them afterwards in your Vector3 like so:
o.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(xIndex * 15,yIndex * 15,0f);

Comment: yup did that already sir . But there's a problem sir after the first iteration it instantiate the whole value i need then after the 2nd iteration sir now it doubles all my prefab. What i mean by 2nd iteration sir is that every 10-15 seconds may data value `P, P, P, B` Adds a letter for example after 15 seconds it will add letter `P` so data value now is `P,P,P,B,P`

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to [Immorality for showing me his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50126599/increment-position-if-string-data-array-is-different-c-sharp-unity/50128716#50128716), and it was actually the correct one, but missing the condition:

```
if (table.GetLength(0) < xIndex)
            {
                break;
            }

            if (previousValue.Equals(newPreviousValue) && yIndex < table.GetLength(1))
            {
                yIndex += 1;
                table[xIndex, yIndex] = previousValue;
            }
            else
            {
                xIndex += 1;
                yIndex = 0;
                table[xIndex, yIndex] = previousValue;
            }
            newPreviousValue = previousValue;
```

so instead of `table.GetLength(1) < yIndex` it must be `yIndex < table.GetLength(1)`.